# Find the distribution of $X$ from the linear equation $AX = b$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and that $b$ is a vector with coefficients of independent random variables $a_{ij}, b_i$ of the law $N(0,1)$ (standard normal distribution). Suppose that $X$ is a vector with coefficients of random variables satisfying $AX = b$, can we say that $X_i$ is of uniform distribution (or that $X_i$ is constant)?

I know that the linear combination of normal distributions is also of normal distribution, is this is the only case?

Comment: suppose you might try first to analyze the case 2x2

Comment: You're saying $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are independent and have standard normal distributions, and the entries of $A$, i.e. $a_{ij}$ are also independent and have standard normal distributions? If so, then the conditional distribution of $X$ given $A$ can be found quite routinely, but beyond that it seems like a harder problem. $\qquad$

Comment: I have figured out the case $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, for $n \ge 3$, I don't know the distribution law of the product of several standard normal distributions.